# Vue (smooth) Drag and Drop to trigger js-script (not for sorting)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, draggable

I would like to misuse a drag and drop function for other purposes.

The goal is to execute an event of the container (being dropped on) when the drop occurs.
There should be no assignment or sorting.

I just want a js event to be triggered on @drop.
Actually, I have several containers for various options of the element.

Simplified example:
Let's imagine a traffic light.
Now I have three containers. Depending on which container a (any) element is dragged onto, the respective traffic light should light up.
Nothing else should happen to the actual (drawn element).

However, for drop to be allowed, all containers (source and destination) must be assigned to the same group or group name/tag.

```html
// sourcecontainer that contains elemets to drag
<Container behaviour="drop-zone" group-name="tl" style="width:100%;">
  <Draggable ...>
    ...
  </Draggable>
</Container>

// destinationcontainer that shoult trigger the js-events
<Container behaviour="move" group-name="tl" style="width:100%;" @drop="red_light()">
</Container>

<Container behaviour="move" group-name="tl" style="width:100%;" @drop="yellow_light()">
</Container>

<Container behaviour="move" group-name="tl" style="width:100%;" @drop="green_light()">
</Container>
```

However, my problem is that in this case @drop is applied to all containers with this group name/tag.
In any case, the light that is defined in the first defined container would always shine.

In my attempts so far I have only achieved that the red lamp always lights up (no matter which container I move into, since the function of the first defined container appears to be used), or that all lamps light up.

How can I get my desired result with vue.js?
I'm happy to use options other than "(smooth) dnd".

**The standard html-option ["draggable"](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_ondrag.asp) seems not working in vue. The "ondragstart" and "ondragend" events were triggered, but the element is't really dragged.**